# Two buttons show two fragments

Tags: android

I'm working on having 2 buttons on the same activity. By default, the content of button 1 is displayed. When button 2 is clicked, the button 1 fragment is replaced with button 2 fragment. However, I'm having problem running my code, and my app always crashes, and I have no idea why. Please help...

In my main activity's xml, I have 2 buttons, both with onclick to "selectFrag. And I have a  below them. Note that in , I have specified Fragment1 as the default fragment.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tab1"
    android:onClick="selectFrag"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tab2"
    android:onClick="selectFrag"/>

<fragment
    android:name="com.example.toshiba.weehaufyp.Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1"/>
```

In my main activity's java,

```
tab1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tab1);
tab2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tab2);

public void selectFrag(View view){
    Fragment fr;

    if(view == findViewById(R.id.tab2)){
        fr = new Fragment2();
    }
    else{
        fr = new Fragment1();
    }

....
....

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

In my 2 fragments' xmls,

```
<LinearLayout ... ...>
    <TextView
     ... .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

I left the java of the 2 fragments untouched. They have the default code. Such as

```
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
```

and some methods like OnFragmentInteractionListener, onCreate, onCreateView, onAttach, onDetach, all of which have default code.

Comment: can you post some stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

You have hard defined a fragment in the XML layout. Fragment's that are defined in the XML layout cannot be replaced or removed. Hence you are getting this error. Remove the declaration in the XML and instead add  Fragment1 programmatically in the code (inside your onCreate() method).